# Color coding cells in datagridview based on cell value

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a daily planner, in which tasks are entered into a `datagridview` as follows:

[image]

Tasks also have a priority set by the user, as seen above.

I'm trying to achieve the following, however, I'm not sure how to code this:

If the priority is set to "High" then the cell in which the priority is displayed will change its color to red.

If the priority is set to "Medium" then the cell in which the priority is displayed will change its color to yellow.

If the priority is set to "Low" then the cell in which the priority is displayed will change its color to green.

How would I go about achieving such a feature?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: You should handle the `CellFormatting` event. In that event, you can query the current row/column/cell for a particular value and then change the Row or Cell BackColor appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
For each row As DataGridViewRow In Datagridview1
   If row.Cells(3).Text.Trim  = "High" Then
        row.Cells(3).Style.Backcolor = Color.Red
   Else If row.Cells(3).Text.Trim  = "Low" Then
       ...
   Else If row.Cells(3).Text.Trim = "Medium" Then
      ...
   End If
Next
```